# Sending large amount of data to ASHX handler

Tags: javascript, ashx, generic-handler

I need to send a pretty large amount of data from a web application to a ASHX handler.  The handler will then send the data to a web service for a response. ( The reason the handler is dealing with the web service is because the web app is written in classic ASP and with the handler I am using .NET so I can just consume the service. )

What I need to do is send data to the handler with Javascript.  Right now I am using an XMLHttpRequest and opening the correct URL.  But I do not want to send a large amount of data through the query string.  So my question is, how would I send a large amount of data to the handler?  If there is another way besides using XMLHttpRequest, I am all ears.

Thanks

Comment: What is the format of the data you wanna post? I mean is it a large file? Your form has a lot data to post? what is it exactly. It's important.

Comment: It will include many different objects.  Including two address objects ( sending and receiving ), Package objects ( height, width, depth, weight, etc ), Carrier selection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a **POST** request instead of a **GET** request

Generally data sent by `get` is appended to Query string ..

Data sent by `post` is not appended to query string

```
var url = "get_data.ashx";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";

http.open("POST", url, true);

http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.send(params);
```

Comment: From the handler would I grab the 'params' by doing 'context.Request.Form["params"];' ?

Comment: nope ... you would do context.Request.Form["lorem"]; and context.Request.Form["name"];